# WP8.1 RichTextBox displaying blank screen

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, richtextbox

Good afternoon! 
Let me preface that I am a daily user of this site and am relatively new to c# and WP8 programming. I have a RichTextBox that I am trying to put some imagines in from an API. In essence I am trying to search a string for {value} (They are inclosed in {} for ease) and replacing them with the correct image. Being new I created a stand alone where I enter said text (simplified version) and am trying it for one item before starting huge. Here is what my code looks like ATM:

XAML for RTB:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="Rtb_cardText" Margin="0,310,0,229" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Code behind in MainPage:

```
private void Prime()
        {
            string example = "blah blah blah {T} blah blah blah";
            Paragraph old = new Paragraph();
            Paragraph newer = new Paragraph();

            string[] holder = example.Split(new[] { '{', '}' });

            for (int i = 0; i < holder.Count(); i++)
            {

                if (holder[i] == "t" || holder[i] == "T")
                {

                    Image symbol = new Image();
                    symbol.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/t.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    symbol.Height = Width = 25;
                    InlineUIContainer symbolUI = new InlineUIContainer();
                    symbolUI.Child = symbol;
                    old.Inlines.Add(symbolUI);

                }

                else
                {
                    Run txt = new Run();
                    txt.Text = holder[i];
                    old.Inlines.Add(txt);
                }

                newer = old;
                Rtb_cardText.Blocks.Remove(old);
                Rtb_cardText.Blocks.Add(newer);
            }

        }
```

So my RTB should have "blah blah blah Image blah blah blah".

Everything works to be expected. I dont get any compile errors and I can run the app but once the Method completes I get brought to what seems to be a text input screen. I can bring up the keyboard and attempt to type something in, but nothing shows up. The back button brings me to the Windows main menu of the virtual phone.

Things I have tried are `IsEnabled` and `IsReadOnly`

Any suggestions? Maybe I am missing something simple here. To me it seems that the app is trying to allow text input from the RTB, but I'm not entirely sure. Sorry if I am not making any sense, let me know if I need to clear something up. Thanks for your efforts! :)

Update - Commented out the image part and the if/else and just had it dump without checking for the image and my text comes though fine just without the image. So it shows it as "blah blah blah T blah blah blah"

So the code that works without image is:

```
private void Prime()
            {
                string example = "blah blah blah {T} blah blah blah";
                Paragraph old = new Paragraph();
                Paragraph newer = new Paragraph();

                string[] holder = example.Split(new[] { '{', '}' });

                for (int i = 0; i < holder.Count(); i++)
                {

                    if (holder[i] == "t" || holder[i] == "T")
                    {

                        //Image symbol = new Image();
                        //symbol.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/t.png", UriKind.Relative));
                        //symbol.Height = Width = 25;
                        //InlineUIContainer symbolUI = new InlineUIContainer();
                        //symbolUI.Child = symbol;
                        //old.Inlines.Add(symbolUI);

                    //}

                    //else
                    //{
                        Run txt = new Run();
                        txt.Text = holder[i];
                        old.Inlines.Add(txt);
                    //}

                    newer = old;
                    Rtb_cardText.Blocks.Remove(old);
                    Rtb_cardText.Blocks.Add(newer);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
symbol.Height = Width = 25;
```

Was the issue I was running into. I was trying to set both values at once.

```
symbol.Height = 25;
symbol.Width = 25;
```

This makes everything work like a charm! Since I commented out the image part and it worked I figured it had to be there, and it was! :)